# Caution against a person belittling himself

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits

BH

I heard someone say that a person should never say "I am this [negative character trait]" or "I am that [negative character trait]" because Chas ve Shalom Hashem can bring that negative character trait upon him. What’s the source of this? And if someone did this how can they annul this?

Comment: אל תפתח את הפה לשטן

Comment: Sefer Chassidim 480

Answer (score 1):

The מהרש"א כתובות ח ע"ב in the חידושי אגדות (I can't find a link to it neither in Hebrew Books nor in Sefaria) writes:
לעולם אל יפתח אדם פיו כו' הוא מבואר שהדבור גם בדרך הדמיון מעורר את מדת הדין עד שהשטן מקטרג להיות החוטא מודה בדבר שראוי לכך *The reason is that speech, even if only used as a comparison, can awaken the strict measure of justice, and the Satan will be able to use that as an accusation, claiming that the speaker (with his words) agreed to that accusation*.
I presume that by repenting for saying these words (and possibly start saying nice things about himself) he can undo it, but I have no source for that, besides that תשובה is always accepted.